# If $A$ is an orthogonal matrix, then $d(u,v)=d(Au, Av)$ for all $u, v \in R^n$.

Tags: linear-algebra

> If $A$ is an orthogonal matrix, then $d(u,v)=d(Au, Av)$ for all vectors $u, v \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

I'm at a loss of how to proceed here. The distance metric $d(u,v)$ is defined by $d(u,v)=\|u-v\|=\sqrt{\sum (u_i-v_i)^2}$, but after this I have no idea how to proceed. I understand that an orthogonal transformation is supposed to preserve the dot product and length (ie, $\|AX\|=\|X\|$ and $AX\cdot AY=X\cdot Y$) but I'm not sure how it applies to the distance metric.

Something I have tried is obviously writing out the columns of $A = (a_1, a_2... a_n)$ and doing $\|A(u-v)\|=\|a_1(u_1-v_1)+a_2(u_2-v_2)+ \dots + a_n(u_n-v_n)\|$, but it doesn't get me anywhere to the form I want.

I don't actually want a solution, any hints will do. Also, I'm technically not allowed to use the angle-preserving property of orthogonal transformations yet as it is meant to be proved in the later part of the question.

Comment: Prove that it is equivalent to showing $\|u-v\|^2_2=\|A(u-v)\|_2^2$ using the definition of $d$ and squaring.

Comment: The norm is also given by $\|x\|^2 = \langle x , x \rangle$. What is $A^TA$ if $A$ is orthogonal?

Comment: @J.G Ah okay I got it, it's because ||Ax||=||x|| if A is orthogonal?